# How to ask for user input mid-execution?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app which basically goes through a while loop and reads XML documents. However, the file path must be manually entered by the user each time.

I need to interrupt the execution, provide a text box or something to type in the file path and then continue after the input. I have read several answers but haven't found one that addresses this case.

This is how the code looks like:

```
private void BTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int s = 1;
    while (s < 10)
    { if (condition == true)
         {
           XDocument mydocument = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\me\\mydocument.xml");
           string XML2Str = mydocument.ToString();
           if (XML2Str.Contains("bingo"))
              { //do stuff//}
         }
         s++;
    }
 }
```

Currently I can use only one file path. Instead of having the file path in the code, I want the user to enter it.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following code ?

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                Filter = "All Files | *.*"
            };

            while (true)
            {
                var b = dialog.ShowDialog();
                if (b == null || !b.Value)
                    break;

                MessageBox.Show(dialog.FileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

## may it help

```
private void BTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    load(textbox1.Text);
  }catch(Exception ex){ MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}
}

void load(string _path)
{
  int s = 1;
   while (s < 10)
   { if (condition == true)
      {
        XDocument mydocument = XDocument.Load(_path);
        string XML2Str = mydocument.ToString();
        if (XML2Str.Contains("bingo"))
          { //do stuff//}
      }
     s++;
  }
}
```